# Prompt date as input parameter in crystal report using SQL Query

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports-2010

I need to write a query to prompt for input date in crystal reports. I have written query as follows.

```
SUM (DECODE (TO_CHAR (TRUNC(READ_DATE), 'DD-MON-YYYY') = '{?READ_DATE}',salary,0)) SAL
```

But it is giving non-numeric exception.

Please help.

Comment: I found answer that, we need to write in query like
SUM (DECODE (TO_CHAR (TRUNC(READ_DATE), 'DD-MON-YYYY') = {?READ_DATE},salary,0)) SAL
and need to create parameter in crystal report.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer that, we need to write in query like `SUM (DECODE (TO_CHAR (TRUNC(READ_DATE), 'DD-MON-YYYY') = {?READ_DATE},salary,0)) SAL` and need to create parameter for 'READ_DATE' in crystal report.